# Prove that a certain series grows as $O(\log n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

The problem below is an exercise that came up during self-study. I cannot even easily convince myself of its truth.

**Problem:** There is a sequence of reals $1 = a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \ldots \leq a_n$ satisfying $a_{i+1}-a_i \leq \sqrt{a_i}$ for all $1 \leq i < n$. Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{a_{i+1}-a_i}{a_i} \leq O(\log n).$$

As a first step, letting $f(n)$ denote the LHS in the desired inequality, we can write $$f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{a_i}}.$$ My next thought is to show that this is less than a series that we know grows as $O(\log n)$, maybe the harmonic series, but I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit the question text to show what you've tried so far, and especially anything you had difficulty with, and possibly also provide other context such as where the question comes from. Thanks.

Comment: Is the sequence infinite or finite? Asymptotic analysis of this sort usually only makes sense if we are allowed to take $n \to \infty$, but here it seems $n$ is fixed.

Comment: Yes, it is implicit that we take $n \to \infty$. Sorry for the informal statement, I tried to copy the problem here without much modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$a_{k+1} \le a_k+\sqrt{a_k} < a_k + \sqrt{a_k}+\tfrac{1}{4} = \left(\sqrt{a_k}+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2,$$ i.e. $\sqrt{a_{k+1}} < \sqrt{a_k}+\tfrac{1}{2}$ for all $k$. Hence, we can use induction to show that $\sqrt{a_n} \le \tfrac{n+1}{2}$ for all $n$.

Then for all $n$, we have:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1}\dfrac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{a_k} &\le \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1}\dfrac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{\left(\sqrt{a_{k+1}}-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2} & \text{since} \ \sqrt{a_{k+1}} < \sqrt{a_k}+\tfrac{1}{2}
\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1}\int_{a_k}^{a_{k+1}}\dfrac{1}{\left(\sqrt{a_{k+1}}-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2}\,dx 
\\
&\le \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1}\int_{a_k}^{a_{k+1}}\dfrac{1}{\left(\sqrt{x}-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2}\,dx & \text{since} \ \dfrac{1}{(\sqrt{x}-\tfrac{1}{2})^2} \ \text{is decreasing}
\\
&= \int_{1}^{a_n}\dfrac{1}{\left(\sqrt{x}-\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2}\,dx 
\\
&= \left[2\log\left(2\sqrt{x}-1\right) - \dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{x}-1}\right]_{1}^{a_n}
\\
&= 2\log\left(2\sqrt{a_n}-1\right) - \dfrac{2}{2\sqrt{a_n}-1} + 2 
\\
&\le 2\log\left(2\sqrt{a_n}-1\right)+2 
\\
&\le 2 \log n + 2. & \text{since} \ \sqrt{a_n} \le \tfrac{n+1}{2}
\end{align*}

Therefore, $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1}\dfrac{a_{k+1}-a_k}{a_k} = O(\log n)$ as desired.

Comment: Thank you. Could you also briefly explain the thought process that lead you to the initial steps? I can see how it falls into place once you write the inequality using $\sqrt{a_{k+1}} < \sqrt{a_k} + \frac{1}{2}$, but I find it difficult to think of trying your initial steps.

Comment: I was playing around with writing the sum as a Riemann sum for some integral (a technique which I've used on many similar problems), and eventually got to a point where I needed an upper bound on $a_n$. If we had $a_{k+1} = a_k+\sqrt{a_k}$ for all $k$ (instead of $\le$), then you can play around with it to see that $a_k$ grows quadratically, which sort of motivates finding a quadratic upper bound for $a_k$.

Comment: I see, thank you very much.